# custom sort in multi groupby laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

This is my query in laravel.

query:

```
  $rank = Score::selectRaw('AVG(score) average, course_id, customer_id')
    ->groupBy('course_id' , 'customer_id')->get();
```

output:

```
    [
{"average":14,"course_id":1,"customer_id":1},
{"average":10,"course_id":1,"customer_id":2},
{"average":20,"course_id":1,"customer_id":3},
{"average":11,"course_id":7,"customer_id":1},
{"average":19,"course_id":7,"customer_id":3}]
```

I want to sort the average of each course and have the information as follows. please guide me
for example:

```
rank ['course_id'] : customer  |  average: 

rank[1][0]: customer: 3 average: 20
rank[1][1]: customer: 1 average: 14
rank[1][2]: customer: 2 average: 10
rank[7][0]: customer: 3 average: 19
rank[7][1]: customer: 1 average: 11
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a ->sortBy('average') after the groupBy?

Comment: not work. Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy does not exist.

Comment: Have you tried the [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be do like this

```
$rank = Score::selectRaw('AVG(score) average, course_id, customer_id')
    ->groupBy('course_id' , 'customer_id')->get();
$rank = $rank->sortByDesc('average')->groupBy('customer_id');
foreach($rank as $customerId => $items) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $customerId  . ' customer ' . $item->customer_id . ' average ' . $item->average . PHP_EOL;
        // then your logic  
    }
}
```